# Show that the Taylor Series converges uniformly to $f$

Tags: real-analysis

In Apostol's Real Analysis textbook he mentions without proof the following:

> Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable. Let $$P_n (x) = \sum_{k=0} ^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k .$$
>   Suppose that for all $R>0$ there exists $M$ such that $|f^{(n)} (x)| \leq M$ for all $n$. Then $$\sum_{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)} (x_0)}{k!}
> (x-x_0)^k$$
>   converges uniformly to $f$ on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

From an earlier section we know that there exists $c \in (x_0,x)$ such that
$$f(x) = P_n (x) + \frac{f^{(n+1) } (c)}{(n+1)!} (x-x_0)^{n+1} $$ but I am not sure if or how this could help prove his claim.

Comment: Do you mean $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le M$ for all $n?$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: To check uniform convergence on compact sets, it suffices to check on all intervals $[-R,R]$. Fix such an interval an use the last identity you wrote down (the one involving $c$) to bound $|f(x)-P_n(x)|$. You'll have to use that the factorial grows faster than the exponential.

Comment: I’m wondering where the exponential function appears? (Also, we are just considering $P_n$ in the bound since the uniform convergence would take care of the infinite taylor series right?)

Comment: @Compact By exponential, I meant that $R^n/n!\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $R$, not the actual $e^x$. I can elaborate if needed.